# pass div value to another php is blank?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a div in form , I try to POST the value to another php  using $_POS['calander'] in value.php , but it just return blank ,
how to get the div value from another php  ?

```
<form id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="value.php" method="post">
<div id="calander" class="pull-left" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar" id="reportrange_right"></i>

<span>&nbsp</span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>
</form>
```

How do I post the div value to another php ?

Comment: can you post your json op ?

Comment: div has doesn't value ! Which you want to get !Also note data post is can make by html input and javascript ,not php..

Comment: @DavidJawphan What do you mean with "_data post is can make by html input and javascript ,not php_"? You can still use post without even using javascript because it's a necessity with PHP-with-Database thing.

Comment: I mean he want to post div value !That is can't do by php ,but if he change its to html input element or doing by javascript will enable for that Q.. @rhavendc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this it may help you ,

```
<form id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="value.php" method="post">
<div id="calander" class="pull-left" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar" id="reportrange_right"></i>
 <span>&nbsp</span> <b class="caret"></b>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="hiddeninput" name="hiddeninput">
  <input type="submit" id="subs" name="subs" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#subs').click(function () {
       var mysave = $('#calander').html();
        $('#hiddeninput').val(mysave);
       });
     });
   </script>
```

in your `PHP` Page use ,

```
 $_POST['hiddeninput'];
```

to receive the value

Answer (score 0):

Send form data is only working with input element ! So you need to create input element to do that. If you know jQuery, can make easily by ajax method. Here is Javascript `OnClick` example I have tried ....

```
<form id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="value.php" method="post" onclick="Send(this)">
<div id="calander" class="pull-left" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar" id="reportrange_right"></i>

<span>&nbsp</span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Send(t) {
    var data = document.getElementById('calander');//get div element
    var divinput = document.createElement("input");//create new input
    divinput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');       //type hidden
    divinput.setAttribute('name','calander');      //set post name
    divinput.setAttribute('value', data.innerHTML);//send div value(html)
    t.appendChild(divinput);                       //You must append current form before submit
    t.submit();
    return false;
        }
</script>
```